# where do i put overrideMode="Deny" in mt config

Tags: c#, asp.net, config

**I have got this error below**

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the     page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information

Module  Authentication

Notification    AuthenticateRequest

Handler ExtensionlessUrl

Handler-Integrated-4.0

Error Code  0x80070021

Config Error    This configuration section cannot be used at this path. 
    This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by 
    default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with 
    overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

**this is my config file**

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="data source=12.12.16.117;Initial Catalog=web_prof_global; User ID=1111;Password=1111;persist security info=True;packet size=4096" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DBConnectionSf" connectionString="data source=12.12.16.117;Initial Catalog=webCommon; User ID=1111;Password=1111;persist security info=True;packet size=4096" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
   <system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"  />

    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="s-f.aspx" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>

</system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

can you please help

Comment: How is your site hosted? If IIS - then is it installed correctly? Is there other sites running (successfully on the same host)?

Comment: external hosting provider. i dont have access to IIS. this is an module attached onto the site. with its own config file

Comment: OK, I see. Is it running on Integrated or Classic "Managed Pipeline Mode"? And it's working on local or test environment?

Comment: The "Managed Pipeline Mode" has configured as Integrated mode. it works fine on my server. i have migrated to an new server and it comes up with the error